# Xcode errors with libgcrypt

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, macos

In my program, I originally added json-c to it and had some missing dependencies related to libgcrypt. Now, I am getting these errors for libgcrypt that do not make any sense to me. Has anyone seen these before or are able to tell what in the world I did wrong?

```
CompileC /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mpih-add1-4D47DD99C77BE382.o PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S normal x86_64 assembler-with-cpp com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge
    setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x assembler-with-cpp -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -fasm-blocks -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -iquote /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/PianoLounge-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/PianoLounge-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/PianoLounge-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/PianoLounge-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug/include -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Products/Debug -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mpih-add1-4D47DD99C77BE382.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mpih-add1-4D47DD99C77BE382.dia -c /Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S -o /Users/jordan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PianoLounge-ajgojrzszrergafgvyuliphwxcpg/Build/Intermediates/PianoLounge.build/Debug/PianoLounge.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/mpih-add1-4D47DD99C77BE382.o

/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:33:16: error: unexpected token in '.set'
 .set noreorder
               ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:34:11: error: unexpected token in '.set'
 .set noat
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:38:2: error: unknown directive
 .ent _gcry_mpih_add_n
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:40:2: error: unknown directive
 .frame $30,0,$26,0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:42:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $3,0($17)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:43:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $4,0($18)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:45:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
 subq $19,1,$19
            ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:46:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 and $19,4-1,$2 # number of limbs in first loop
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:47:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bis'
 bis $31,$31,$0
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:48:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'beq'
 beq $2,.L0 # if multiple of 4 limbs, skip first loop
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:50:11: error: invalid operand for instruction
 subq $19,$2,$19
          ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:52:19: error: invalid operand for instruction
.Loop0: subq $2,1,$2
                  ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:53:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $5,8($17)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:54:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $4,$0,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:55:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $6,8($18)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:56:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:57:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $3,$4,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:58:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$3,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:59:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $4,0($16)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:60:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:62:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $17,8,$17
            ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:63:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $18,8,$18
            ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:64:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bis'
 bis $5,$5,$3
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:65:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bis'
 bis $6,$6,$4
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:66:13: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $16,8,$16
            ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:67:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bne'
 bne $2,.Loop0
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:69:6: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'beq'
.L0: beq $19,.Lend
     ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:72:19: error: invalid operand for instruction
.Loop: subq $19,4,$19
                  ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:74:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $5,8($17)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:75:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $4,$0,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:76:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $6,8($18)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:77:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:78:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $3,$4,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:79:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$3,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:80:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $4,0($16)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:81:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:83:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $3,16($17)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:84:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $6,$0,$6
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:85:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $4,16($18)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:86:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $6,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:87:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $5,$6,$6
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:88:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $6,$5,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:89:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $6,8($16)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:90:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:92:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $5,24($17)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:93:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $4,$0,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:94:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $6,24($18)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:95:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:96:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $3,$4,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:97:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$3,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:98:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $4,16($16)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:99:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:101:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $3,32($17)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:102:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $6,$0,$6
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:103:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 ldq $4,32($18)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:104:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $6,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:105:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $5,$6,$6
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:106:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $6,$5,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:107:12: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $6,24($16)
           ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:108:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:110:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $17,32,$17
             ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:111:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $18,32,$18
             ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:112:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $16,32,$16
             ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:113:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'bne'
 bne $19,.Loop
 ^~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:115:16: error: invalid operand for instruction
.Lend: addq $4,$0,$4
               ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:116:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$0,$1
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:117:10: error: invalid operand for instruction
 addq $3,$4,$4
         ^~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:118:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'cmpult'
 cmpult $4,$3,$0
 ^~~~~~
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:119:11: error: unexpected token in memory operand
 stq $4,0($16)
          ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:120:2: error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
 or $0,$1,$0
 ^
/Users/jordan/Projects/Cocoa/PianoLounge/PianoLounge/libgcrypt/mpi/alpha/mpih-add1.S:123:2: error: unknown directive
 .end _gcry_mpih_add_n
 ^
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

I made sure to only include the needed files (.h and .c) and it cleared up the errors I was receiving, but now I am back to receiving the linker errors.

http://pastebin.com/VM0aBU1m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I'm an idiot. I don't know why I felt the need to add these libraries in manually. I ended up using MacPorts to get the required libraries and it worked great.

Comment: Homebrew may be an alternative you could look at: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew. It is generally more up to date than MacPorts, and uses /usr/local which is already in the compilers include/library path rather than /opt like MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

in the previous question you asked (an hour ago?) you said you copied the whole libgcrypt folder *wholesale* (i.e. entirely) into your current project.  From what I can tell up there, Xcode is spewing errors on a file that ends with the suffix "`.S`". Xcode doesn't know what to do with them. And I don't know what they are.

Really, all you need is to include into your project are the files from libgcrypt that are appropriate for what you are trying to do.

That likely being... "`include`" or "`import`" header files that end with the suffix "`.h`", the actual "`.framework`" or "`.a`" or "`.dylib`" library files.

That's it.

If my answer doesn't get you to your solution, please edit your question to show a screenshot of what your project looks like in Xcode, and especially how those included files look in the File Inspector.

Comment: I updated my post. What you suggested did fix those errors, but now I am receiving the errors I was previously. I'm very new to OSX development, but this doesn't seem like it should be giving me this much grief.